# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n(1-(x/n))^ne^{x/2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$$
\mbox{How to compute}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,\int_{0}^{n}\left(1 -{x \over n}\right)^{n}
\,\mathrm{e}^{x/2}\,\,\mathrm{d}x\,\,\, ?.
$$

No ideas how to start this one. I see that the limit of the
$\left[1 - \left(x/n\right)^{n}\right]$ looks close to being $\,\mathrm{e}$, but it should be a plus sign instead of a minus sign$\ldots$

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^{-x}$.

Comment: Ah, then if I could somehow interchange the integral and limit, I would have $e^{-x}e^{x/2}=e^{-x/2}$ as the integrand. But that leads to the next problem, of how to justify the interchange...

Comment: Would I have to show that the integrand is uniformly convergent, or is there an easier way using either Dominated Convergence or MonotoneConvergence?

Comment: Show first that $\log(1-z)\leq -z$ for $z\in [0,1($, apply with $z=x/n$, $x\in [0,n[$, take the exponential, and try to use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Kelenner I hadn't seen your comment and gave essentially the same answer. I deleted mine for now, so maybe you would like to give an answer.

Comment: @zhw I do not want to make a complete answer (this is why I have made a short an incomplete comment), so please undelete your answer, so that a good answer could be given. Thanks very much for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar limit is used to prove [Euler's limit product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for the $\Gamma$ function:
$$ t! = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n! n^t}{(t+1)(t+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(t+n)}\tag{1}.$$
For any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have
$$ \max_{n\geq x} \left(1-x/n\right)^n\leq e^{-x}\tag{2} $$
and $e^{-x}\cdot e^{x/2}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$, hence by monotone or [dominated convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we have:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{n}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{x/2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x/2}\,dx = \color{red}{2}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: How do we use monotone convergence here if the integrand is decreasing?

Comment: @Marshant: tht has nothing to do with the hyphotesis of the monotone convergence theorem. For a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the sequence given by $\max(0,(1-x/n)^n)$ is increasing towards $e^{-x}$.

Comment: And anyway, a decreasing function is still a monotone function.

Comment: Sorry, so just to clarify if you were to use DCT, you would use $\max\{0,(1-x/n)^n\}$ as the dominating $L_1$ function? I guess I'm just a bit confused how you knew how to choose it in this kind of way.

Comment: @Marshant: I use $e^{-x}$ as a dominating function for the functions $f_n(x)=(1-x/n)^n$ supported on $[0,n]$.

Comment: Your inequality (2): What if $x=20, n = 2?$

Comment: @zhw.: how can a $\sup$ on $n$ depend on $n$ ?!

Comment: It doesn't. But take $x=20.$ Then $\max (0, (1-20/2)^2)=81.$ Thus the $\sup$ over $n$ is at least this big.

Comment: @zhw.: all right, there was something to be fixed, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If $0\le x \le n,$ then $(1-x/n)^n \le e^{-x}.$ Proof: This is certainly true at the end points. For $0<x<n,$

$$\tag 1\ln (1-x/n)^n = n \ln (1-x/n) < n(-x/n) = -x.$$

Here we have used the inequality $\ln (1-u) < - u,$ which is valid for $ 0 < u < 1.$ Exponentiate back in $(1)$ to get the desired inequality.

To finish the problem, let $f_n(x) = (1-x/n)^ne^{x/2}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)$ for $x\in [0,\infty).$ Then by the above, $0 \le f_n(x) \le e^{-x/2}, x\ge 0$ You're now good to go for the dominated convergence theorem on $[0,\infty).$